# flash idendify running programs on PC and user competability

Tags: javascript, html, flash

Im looking to recognize running programs on my Client's PC.

I want to recognize their bandwith and see if they have microphone and camera installed.

all this info i want to take from my client pc and repesent it in my server.

Someone done it before?

thanks!

Comment: There is no straight forward way to achieve this as it will be a huge privacy violation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use JavaScript to detect running programs on the PC

However, you can try to use `navigator.getUserMedia` functions to determine whether the client has microphone or camera available

[MDN article on `navigator.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NavigatorUserMedia.getUserMedia)

**note**: *when you call this method, the user will be notified that you are trying to access their camera and/or microphone. They can reject your request and `getUserMedia` will throw an exception*

This feature is implemented slightly differently on different browsers so may not be fully available